# How to loop through table based on unique date in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops, matlab-table

I have this table named `BondData` which contains the following:

```
Settlement  Maturity    Price   Coupon
8/27/2016   1/12/2017   106.901 9.250
8/27/2019   1/27/2017   104.79  7.000
8/28/2016   3/30/2017   106.144 7.500
8/28/2016   4/27/2017   105.847 7.000
8/29/2016   9/4/2017    110.779 9.125
```

For each day in this table, I am about to perform a certain task which is to assign several values to a variable and perform necessary computations. The logic is like:

```
do while Settlement is the same
    m_settle=current_row_settlement_value
    m_maturity=current_row_maturity_value
    and so on...
    my_computation_here...
end
```

It's like I wanted to loop through my settlement dates and perform task for as long as the date is the same.

**EDIT:** Just to clarify my issue, I am implementing Yield Curve fitting using Nelson-Siegel and Svensson models.Here are my codes so far:

```
function NS_SV_Models()

load bondsdata

BondData=table(Settlement,Maturity,Price,Coupon);


BondData.Settlement = categorical(BondData.Settlement);
Settlements = categories(BondData.Settlement); % get all unique Settlement

for k = 1:numel(Settlements)
    rows = BondData.Settlement==Settlements(k);
    Bonds.Settle = Settlements(k); % current_row_settlement_value
    Bonds.Maturity = BondData.Maturity(rows); % current_row_maturity_value
    Bonds.Prices=BondData.Price(rows);
    Bonds.Coupon=BondData.Coupon(rows);

    Settle = Bonds.Settle; 
    Maturity = Bonds.Maturity; 

    CleanPrice = Bonds.Prices;
    CouponRate = Bonds.Coupon; 
    Instruments = [Settle Maturity CleanPrice CouponRate];

    Yield = bndyield(CleanPrice,CouponRate,Settle,Maturity);

NSModel = IRFunctionCurve.fitNelsonSiegel('Zero',Settlements(k),Instruments);
SVModel = IRFunctionCurve.fitSvensson('Zero',Settlements(k),Instruments);

NSModel.Parameters
SVModel.Parameters

end

end
```

Again, my main objective is to get each model's parameters (beta0, beta1, beta2, etc.) on a per day basis. I am getting an error in `Instruments = [Settle Maturity CleanPrice CouponRate];` because Settle contains only one record (8/27/2016), it's suppose to have two since there are two rows for this date. Also, I noticed that Maturity, CleanPrice and CouponRate contains all records. They should only contain respective data for each day.

Hope I made my issue clearer now. By the way, I am using MATLAB R2015a.

Comment: what have you tried so far? do you have a minimal, complete and verifiable example of your code?

Comment: I tried to get the unique settlement date with something like this but I have a problem on how to implement the looping                                                                                        load bondsdata

 A=table(Settlement,Maturity, Price, Coupon);
 

B=unique(A(:,1),'rows');

Comment: Which MATLAB version do you use?

Comment: I am using MATLAB R2015a. Kindly see my updated codes above for some clarifications. Hope you guys can help me further.Thanks..

Comment: In your example `8/27/2016` appears only once, the other date is `8/27/2019`. See me edited answer below with regard to your edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use categorical array. Here is your function (without its' headline, and all rows I can't run are commented):

```
BondData = table(datetime(Settlement),datetime(Maturity),Price,Coupon,...
    'VariableNames',{'Settlement','Maturity','Price','Coupon'});
BondData.Settlement = categorical(BondData.Settlement);
Settlements = categories(BondData.Settlement); % get all unique Settlement

for k = 1:numel(Settlements)
    rows = BondData.Settlement==Settlements(k);
    Settle = BondData.Settlement(rows); % current_row_settlement_value
    Mature = BondData.Maturity(rows); % current_row_maturity_value
    CleanPrice = BondData.Price(rows);
    CouponRate = BondData.Coupon(rows);

    Instruments = [datenum(char(Settle)) datenum(char(Mature))...
        CleanPrice CouponRate];
%     Yield = bndyield(CleanPrice,CouponRate,Settle,Mature);
%     
%     NSModel = IRFunctionCurve.fitNelsonSiegel('Zero',Settlements(k),Instruments);
%     SVModel = IRFunctionCurve.fitSvensson('Zero',Settlements(k),Instruments);
%     
%     NSModel.Parameters
%     SVModel.Parameters
end
```

Keep in mind the following:

1. You cannot concat different types of variables as you try to do in: `Instruments = [Settle Maturity CleanPrice CouponRate];`
2. There is no need in the structure `Bond`, you don't use it (e.g. `Settle = Bonds.Settle;`).
3. Use the relevant functions to convert between a `datetime` object and string or numbers. For instance, in the code above: `datenum(char(Settle))`. I don't know what kind of input you need to pass to the following functions.

Comment: Thanks for your swift reply. Please bear with me as I was totally a newbie in MATLAB. I am encountering an error in this line of code:Settlements = categories(datetime(BondData.Settlement),'mm-dd-yyyy') which gives a "Undefined function 'categories' for input arguments of type 'datetime'."

Comment: You have to first convert all `BondData.Settlement` to a `datetime` format, then convert it to categorical array, and the use `categories`. See my edit here.

Comment: Thanks so much EBH! I'm totally new in MATLAB and you are so generous in helping me. Got this code running.I'm so impressed.